# Copy to clipboard and paste it at required field in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have an issue with the Cypress. The test is Creating a new user every time and verify if it was created in the cloud. I want to store a dynamic email(which contains a time stamp) in to a variable, and use this variable in another test. Here, the email was created successfully. But, when I Navigate to another URL, it generates another email in the search field inside the cloud.

So, I saw in some blogs using copy to clipboard and paste it. but those functions are not that clear. Any suggestions will be a great help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please review [ask] and provide a [mcve] when asking a question

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save information to use in another test, you can use fixtures. Save the info to a fixture in test 1 using `cy.writeFile`, load from the fixture in test 2 using `cy.fixture`.

Reference:

- Fixture: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture.html#Syntax
- writeFile: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/writefile.html#Syntax

You can save the info in json format which makes it simple to retrieve with `cy.fixture` in the next test.

Example:

```
// inside test 1
cy.writeFile(fixtureAbsoluteFilePath, {email:"foo@foo.com"});
```

```
// inside test 2
cy.fixture(fixtureRelativeFilePath).then((json) => {
  // use data in test
  testSomeStuff(json.email);
}
```

Note that `cy.writeFile` will use the absolute file path to inside the fixture folder and `cy.fixture` uses the path relative to inside the fixture folder.

Comment: Thank you so much @Old Schooled . It was working...